# Hacer un bucle con ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo 7 secciones en una página, formadas por un panel heading y una tabla, la tabla se muestra cuando se pulsa el botón para desplegar en el panel-heading.

La función para desplegar funciona pero quiero usar un indice para no tener que hacer 7 scripts

Código script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#dias1").click(function(){
        $("#desplegable1").slideToggle("slow");
      });
        $("#desplegable1").css({ display: 'none' });
   });   
</script>
```

Desplegable:

```
  <!--Lunes-->
<div class="row" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(117, 178, 212, 0.41);height: 51px; ">
    <p class="col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 20px"><strong>LUNES</strong></p>
    <a href="#" id="dias1" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 5px">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
    </a>
  </div>


  <div class="row">
    <div id="desplegable1">
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table  table-hover">
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--Martes-->

<div class="row" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(117, 178, 212, 0.41);height: 51px; ">
     <p  class="col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 20px"><strong>MARTES</strong></p>
        <a href="#" id="dias2" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="margin-top: 5px">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
        </a>
     </div>
   </div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="desplegable2">
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table  table-hover">
        </table>
      </div>             
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿la tablas se mostrara ne el div llamado desplegable?

Comment: si, se muestra en el desplegable

Comment: ¿y la tabla donde se genera? No aparece en tu código

Comment: Disculpa, supuse que con la explicación bastaría. La tabla es muy grande y para no llenar la pregunta de código espero que con esa indicación sea suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahi puedes ver el code que cree y que funciona perfectamente pruebalo aunque en esa page que te pase no anda pero si lo pones en tu web si que andara la base es que pongas en cada id="dias2" onclick="desplegagle(2)"  id="dias3" onclick="desplegagle(3)" y asi sucesivamente  esta es mi nueva propuesta al final esta el code js que se encargara de hacer lo que pides [Link nueva propuesta](http://www.cubicfactory.com/jseditor/welcome/64045/edit)

Comment: Gracias! Pero eso lo probé y no funcionó :(

Comment: Podrias pasar el code completo porque creo que el code que pasaste anda incompleto... ya que acabo leer muy bn tu code y veo que el js pone #dias y en el code que pasaste pone dias1 en el html por lo que el code que te pase depende de como lo implementes debe funcionar.

Comment: Disculpa, lo copié mal porque el trozo que puse era intentando hacer un bucle y por eso borré los números. Código original:                 
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dias1").click(function(){
                $("#desplegable1").slideToggle("slow");
            });
            $("#desplegable1").css({ display: 'none' });
    });
</script>

Comment: El fragmento de la pregunta es intentando incorporar el bucle de alguna forma, pero no funciona porque su propuesta la probé antes. El código de la sección está bien copiado.

Comment: Vale entonces si haces click en #dias lo que quieres que es el #desplegable de desplieguen todos los dias correcto? los cuales tendran numero al lado de 1 a 7 si es asi ahora mismo te paso code que te funcionara perfecto o cada dia tiene su propio desplegable?

Comment: Cada día tiene su propio desplegable. Voy a añadir más código a la pregunta para que puedas entenderlo mejor :)

Comment: Genial!! Muchas gracias @t8kcontrol !!

Comment: De nada espero que eso es lo que anbabas buscando. Si quieres intento mejorar un poco el code o te sirve ese?

Answer (score 0):

No sé si así está el código pero al final falta cerrar un `div`. Asumiendo que solo omitiste agregar esto a la pregunta procedemos a la respuesta.

Puedes reemplazar el evento del click asignándoselo a una clase en lugar de a un id (en este caso le agregué la clase diasclick al elemento `<a></a>`).

```
<div class="row" style="font-size: 18px;margin-top: 20px">
  <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(117, 178, 212, 0.41);height: 51px; ">
    <p class="col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="margin-bottom: 0px;font-size: 20px"><strong>LUNES</strong></p>
    <a href="#" id="dias1" class="col-md-1 col-lg-1 diasclick" style="margin-top: 5px">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list">click</span>
    </a>
  </div>


<div class="row">
  <div id="desplegable1">
  </div>
</div>
```

y el código en jquery seria de la siguiente forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".diasclick").click(function() {
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     var lastChar = id.substr(id.length - 1); // obtenemos el ultimo caracter del id para saber a cual desplegable lo asignaremos
     $("#desplegable"+lastchar).slideToggle("slow");
 });
     $('*[id^="desplegable"]').css({
        display: 'none'
     });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero no funciona :(  Aparecen todos los desplegables abiertos y sin posibilidad de minimizarlos.

Comment: @Roledi corregí mi respuesta

Comment: No funciona tampoco :(

Comment: Sé más explicito ¿Que es lo que sucede?¿Por qué no funciona?